# How do I change bootstrap colors to custom colors?

Tags: html

I make codes on toyhou.se and I was making a progress bar, and now I'm wondering how to customize the color? Right now, I'm stuck with the bootstrap ones. Is there a way to change this? (No css if possible! Also I use the circlejourney editor if that helps.)

```
<div class="progress my-2 rounded-25"><div class="progress-bar bg-danger progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin ="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%;height:50px;border-radius: 25px;"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All variables in the $theme-colors map are defined as standalone variables. To modify an existing color in our $theme-colors map, add the following to your custom Sass file:

```
$primary: #0074d9;
$danger: #ff4136;
```

Later on, these variables are set in Bootstrap’s $theme-colors map:

```
$theme-colors: (
 "primary": $primary,
  "danger": $danger
);
```